# Ionic 3 Native Camera’s FILE_URI URL on Videos Works But Not on Images

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I am using Ionic3 native camera and I have this in my code:

```
sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
```

However, I get:

> content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A213049

It does not work inside `img src="{{photoUrl}}"`. I would like to upload the file I selected from the photolibrary but the above is what I get. How can I show a preview and upload the file itself. It works for me with videos but not with images. How can I achieve this? Thanks!